# Using Webview in a Adapter

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-adapter

My application has tabs and a tab contain a fragment. There is a cardview in the fragment. I want to when I click the cardview, I want to the webview to work like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCttZ.png) but I'm getting an error.
My webview.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/mywebview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My data Adapter

```
public static class ContentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected TextView title;
    protected TextView description;
    protected TextView date;
    protected ImageView imgSrc;
    protected String urlS;
    protected int itemPos;
    WebView mWebView;
    AdvancedWebView vw;
    public ContentViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        title =  (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        description = (TextView)  v.findViewById(R.id.descript);
        date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);
        imgSrc=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
               /*Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlS));
                v.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);*/
                //there is a problem
                mWebView =(WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.mywebview);
                mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");


            }
        });
    }

}
```

The error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.oguz.topluluk, PID: 3449
                  java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at com.example.oguz.topluluk.WebDataAdapter$ContentViewHolder$1.onClick(WebDataAdapter.java:113)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can I fix it? I'm new to android. Could you guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem. I see that I didn't start the webview maybe there could be another reason, for this reason, I got the error. After a few changes, the final state of code like that;

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ContentViewHolder contentViewHolder, int i) {
    contentViewHolder.theCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {

            /*...*/

            WebView mWebView =new WebView(context);
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.loadUrl(wb.link);


        }
    });

}
```

Definition of the context in another function,

```
  private Context context;
    private List<WebDataInfo> dataList;
    public WebDataAdapter(Context context, List<WebDataInfo> dataList) {
        this.context=context;
        this.dataList = dataList;
}
```

I hope that helps.